# Obtained by reflection method of implementation class

Tags: c#, reflector

```
public void Express(Expression<Func<User, bool>> express)
{
    BLL.Manager.ILogManager logs = BLL.Container.ObjectContainer.getObject<BLL.Manager.ILogManager>();
    logs.GetAll(1);
    var total = logs.LastPageTotal;
}
```

As the above code, I need to know ILogManager the implementation class, I only know that the information reflected the way, but in the method defined type is the type of interface

I've been [through the IL reflecting some call information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/haibo_luo/read-il-from-methodbody), call the information I need to get in the end these by which class to call.

Comment: I've tried reading this a few times, and at the moment I have no idea what's being asked. Could you try to edit it to be clearer?

Comment: Could @Dreampuf be saying he wants to know the concrete implementation of `ILogManager`?

Comment: Yes, As @Daniel A. White said,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to know ILogManager the implementation class

If I understand correctly:

- You've got some code that uses an `ILogManager` variable
- You want to find out which class implements `ILogManager`

You could insert a call to `logs.GetType()` in the code; this will tell you the class type that implements `ILogManager`.

Alternatively, you can tell you which classes implement a given interface the same way that Reflector does: by loading every possible assembly, looking at the types in those assemblies, and recording which ones implement `ILogManager`.

Comment: I can not modify the code inside the method, it is impossible to insert log.GetType (). In addition, if multiple ILogManager implement how match?

Comment: If you can't modify the code then my second suggestion might help. What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes...reflecting all the interfaces, and then look for its implementation class

Comment: You have to do it in reverse: (1) Find all application assemblies; (2) Find all classes in those assemblies; (3) Look at the classes that implement `ILogManager`